# Force second activity to refresh (from mainactivity)

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh

i'm a beginner in android , so excuse me for a perhaps stupid question. I'm developing an App with different Features, wich are chosen in the Menu. By google cloud Messaging the App is also receiving push notifications, which are Stored in an MySQL database. These notifications can be shown in a second listactivity. Now my Problem: when this activity is open and a notification is coming in, it is Stored in database, but the aktive listactivity is not updating, Cause it doesn't know. Howe can i Force my listactivity to Refresh from mainactivity when mainactivity is receiving a notificatipn ? Thanks from Germany Fritz

Answer (score 0):

You can post o a notification (for example from a `Service`) and pass an intent to the corresponding pendingintent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyListActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, my_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
notificationManager.notify(my_notification);
```

And in your MyListAcitity you can override the method `onNewIntent` and reload your data.

Comment: yes i do :) btw, i've a new Problem: When a gcm-pushnotification comes in and i tap on it, the notification gets lost, if my app isn't running. the app gets started, but does't catch the message. if the app is running (even in background), the message ist received by my app and shown. Last Problem: If the users deletes the push notification, the message is lost, isn't stored in sql database.

Comment: Please ask a new question or modify your question and provide some code.